# How to use font-awesome in Bootstrap-wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have created a bootstrap theme in my wordpress.Now i need to implement font-awesome to get Facebook, Twitter icons.  How to link the font-awesome css in bootstrap-template?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by registering fontawesome style in your functions.php file.
    function register_fa(){
        wp_enqueue_style('fontAwesome', 'path_to_fontawesome_css');
    }
    add_action('wp_print_styles', 'register_fa');